# At 50% c, I go party to IC1101 galaxy, and back home. How many times can i go before the expansion of the universe will lock me on one side?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, space-travel, interstellar-travel

*Longer version of the question:*

Let's say I'm an immortal being (I could be artificial) going to "party" to IC1101, one of the biggest galaxies of the universe, 1 billion light-years away from us, and that the speed of my space ship is 50% c. ("c" is the speed of light). Later, I’m coming back to the local galaxy group. But then i'll want to go again several times. How many times back & forward can I go there, before the expansion of the universe would be like parents forbidding parties ?

*Details:*

First I want to mention that I'm surprised that some prestigious & popular  vulgarisation channel, Kurzgesagt, in the video ["How Far Can We Go? Limits of Humanity"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZL4yYHdDSWs) states that it would be "impossible" go out of our local galaxy group, which is quite wrong according to [THIS simple response](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15478/can-we-not-get-outside-the-local-galactic-group/39391#39391), and [THIS](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24180/how-far-can-you-travel-until-you-cant-get-back-to-where-you-started), and [this paper about intergalactic spreading](http://www.fhi.ox.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/intergalactic-spreading.pdf)... of course, to the condition we have a sufficient travel speed. (Even if there is a point in the future where the expansion of the universe will makes it impossible to go out of the local group at any speed, of course.)

So, at 50% c, it takes me about 2,3B years to go to IC1101 (took me a bit more than 2B years because of the expansion of the universe), I’m having a bit of fun there, and then I come back to our local group of galaxies, which takes me another 2,6B years, since distances get bigger again as the universe keeps expanding... (Back home, I see the milky-way already fusing with andromeda, and takes a bit of time to find our sun in this mess) …But then I quickly get bored again, and decide to give another shot to IC1101… then later i'm back again, and etc.

My very awkward guess on a paper corner would be that I could go there, back and forward, about 4 or 5 times, before the expansion of the universe kind of lock me on one of the two sides… …At the end of a journey of 30 to 60 billions years i would guess (the last one-way travel might take quite long).

Am I far off, or slightly correct ? Same question with 90% lightspeed : How many parties at IC1101 ?

*(Well, in the case this is not too far off, knowing the universe will last for a bunch of trillions of years, this - in cases we can travel at such speeds - lives time to choose the best spot to settle before the expansion of the universe isolate groups of galaxies from each other… …Which could give another possible answer to Fermi's paradox. Where are the Aliens?... ...Maybe they are just gone to look asap for another better galaxy group before the universe enters eternal lockdown!... Instead of staying in our small local-group, maybe they went checking the most energetic places possible, for example a huge galaxy like IC1101... huge galaxy also coming with a huge ultramassive black hole, for the old days, to farm its gravitational energy when the stars will be gone.)*

Comment: This might be more appropriate to sci-fi/world-building stack exchange, even if it is about established physics

Comment: @innisfree I don't think so. TBH i'm not at all interested by sci-fi responses at all. Only by scientific ones. The topic here is about the expansion of the universe, how far can we go, and how. Pure science based question. I'm sorry if the original form of the question does not fits you. That's the way i like to discuss cosmological questions. ;-)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/496077/

Comment: I think this is (potentially) a perfectly reasonable Physics SE question so `+1` and welcome to Stack Exchange, but there are two close votes for "Needs details or clarity; This question should include more details and clarify the problem." You did that. You can probably avoid the three more that it takes to close by rewriting it; cleaning it up and shortening and just get to the Physics part of the question. It is good that you have explained your current thinking because it allows people to write a more specific answer to you, but maybe for that you have written much more than is necessary.

Comment: An updated video was uploaded by Kurzgesagt correcting that mistake: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzkD5SeuwzM

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about 90% light-speed but I can answer for 100% .

Based on my limited understanding of physics, I believe the answer is ~16 times (8 round-trip) as our cosmological event horizon is 16 billion light years.

The expansion of the universe happens at a constant rate everywhere in the universe so this number is just as relevant travelling one way 16 billion light years as travelling 8 times round-trip 1 billion light years.

As for 50% or 90%, I am not sure.